# Extra Notification alert

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used Notification Alert for my app and used the below code

```
if(condition){
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notificationIsActive"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    //self.message.text=@"Notifications Started";
    NSTimeInterval interval;
    interval = 5;
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification  
    alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate 
    dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval]; //Enter the time here in 
    seconds.
    localNotification.alertBody= @"Alert time";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval= 
    NSCalendarUnitDay;//NSCalendarUnitMinute;
//Repeating instructions here.

localNotification.soundName= UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}

else
{
    NSArray *arrayOfLocalNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] ;

    for (UILocalNotification *localNotification in arrayOfLocalNotifications) {

        if ([localNotification.alertBody isEqualToString:@"Alert time"]) {
            NSLog(@"the notification this is canceld is %@", localNotification.alertBody);

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification] ; // delete the notification from the system

        }

    }
}
```

Now problem is I got extra notifications showing `this is message Users will see`. I checked everything that there is no extra notification alert I added. Now what can I do? Please help..

EDIT:
One point is missing. I used that notification for testing in my app but later I removed that notification.

Comment: When did you got this extra notification? If you didn't make this notification then it maybe from iOS system.

Comment: I used that notification for testing in my app but later I removed that notification. but its coming and if I uninstall my app then its ok otherwise its coming and coming.

Comment: Maybe it's not canceled properly. You need check this first.

Comment: I checked everything but not got anything like that.

Comment: What about trying **cancelAllLocalNotifications**. BTW this notification is deprecated. Use  UNUserNotificationCenter

Comment: I use **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]** in AppDelegate and its working fine now.